# Hebrew language to a physical keyboard

Tags: external-keyboard, hebrew

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) (Android 4.4.2). Recently I bought a Bluetooth keyboard to go with it.
For English the keyboard works as expected, however I noticed that there is no Hebrew language when adding layouts for the Broadcom BT HID.

I have Hebrew with the virtual keyboard (comes with it - I didn't have to use 3rd party software).

Is there a way to add/install Hebrew so I could use it with the physical keyboard (without 3rd party apps)? As I see it, it is a software thing since the keyboard sends the same signals only the mapping is different.

If no, is there a way to do such a thing with 3rd party apps?

Answer (score 1):

[External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) (costs $2.50) has Hebrew support.